# How to sort a list containing alphanumerical data in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have looked at many forums and threads and none of them worked for my data.
My data is Something like

```
list = ["JohnSmith : 10 cards", "AlexJones : 7 cards", "BillyBob : 19 cards", "JoeBlogs : 21 cards"...]
```

and i want to sort it by numerical order to get the data like (in this case)
AlexJones : 7 cards, JohnSmith : 10 cards, Billybob : 19 cards...
Everything I have tried so far has resulted in errors or sorting by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *key* parameter, of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), for example:

```
import re

lst = ["JohnSmith : 10 cards", "AlexJones : 7 cards", "BillyBob : 19 cards", "JoeBlogs : 21 cards"]


def only_one_digit_group_key(s):
    """This function filters out non-digit characters, assumes only one contiguous group of digits"""
    return int(''.join([e for e in s if e.isdigit()]))


def regex_key(s):
    """This function will extrac the digits from the pattern group of digits followed by cards"""
    return int(re.search(r'(\d+)\s+cards', s).group(1))


print(sorted(lst, key=only_one_digit_group_key))

print(sorted(lst, key=regex_key))
```

**Output**

```
['AlexJones : 7 cards', 'JohnSmith : 10 cards', 'BillyBob : 19 cards', 'JoeBlogs : 21 cards']
['AlexJones : 7 cards', 'JohnSmith : 10 cards', 'BillyBob : 19 cards', 'JoeBlogs : 21 cards']
```

If the above code listing you have two examples of *key* functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the value by a space, the number of cards is always the third element. So you could split by space, convert this element to an int and use it as a key:

```py
lst.sort(key = lambda x : int(x.split(' ')[2]))
```